# sumar datos de un objeto

Tags: php

buen dia tengo este **objeto**

```
[{cantidad: "2"}, {cantidad: "1"}]
```

y quiero sumar mediante php todo lo que me llegue en cantidad y no se como hacerlo alguien puede ayudarme así lo imprimo pero asi me llegan el 2 y el 1 y quiero que se sume todo lo que llegue en cantidad

```
    foreach ($datos as $row) {
      $output[] = $row["cantidad"];
      }
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Deberás primero hacerle un decode a tu objeto por medio de [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)
- Por cierto que para que sea un objeto válido las claves deben venir entre comillas dobles
- Posterior declaras una variable igualada a 0
- Con un ciclo foreach recorres el contenido del objeto
- Accedes a la clave cantidad y por fuera dle ciclo imprimes el total

Código

```
$valores = '
            [
                {"cantidad": "2"},
                {"cantidad": "1"}
            ]
        ';

$valor = json_decode($valores);

$total = 0;
foreach($valor as $data)
{
    $total += $data->cantidad;
}


echo $total;
```

> Con un total de: 3